# Machine learning : How to encore a sub-group of features that are only significant together?

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, feature-extraction

Let’s imagine that I have a dataset of animal body attributes with a lot of features (size or arm, torso, leg, each fingers, etc.).

One of the sub-group of these features are the length or each finger of the hand.

**How can I encode this sub-group of finger lengths so they are only considered together and not independently ? What matters is the “shape of the hand”.**

I don’t want my TREE or KNN to be build in a way that the size of middle finger is independent from the size of the index.

I don't want my algo to find similar a new entry that has exactly the same torso size + exactly the same middle finger size, but a thumb completely different.
What matters is similar torso size + similar hand shape.

I thought about replacing my numerical continuous finger features by a categorical feature that would describe the average shape of the hand.

Basically:

| index | middle | thumb | Shape |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 5 | 2 | index<mid_&_thumb>>middle |
| 4 | 4 | 2 | index=mid_&_thumb>middle |

But it leaves very few flexibility.
Two hands having very similar shapes but one ratio difference would be considered completely different.

If I keep my fingers independent, they are just diluted into the hundreds of features I have.

I don't know anymore if tabular data are the best to represent these data anymore.

Do you have a better suggestion?
For context, I'm using XGB but I think it's a very general question.
Cheers

Comment: Hand shape ratio: Instead of encoding each finger length separately, you could calculate the ratio of each finger length to the length of the hand or  You could also consider using principal component analysis (PCA) to reduce the dimensionality of your data. This would allow you to capture the underlying patterns in the data, including any correlations between finger lengths, without having to manually engineer new features.

Comment: Can you please give a code example of what you are trying to do? There are other stack exchange sites for data science concepts.

Answer (score 0):

You can regard the length of three fingers as a 3-dim vector, then 'the shape of hand' is the direction of this vector. So you can put this 3-dim vector into spherical coordinates so that [index,middle,thumb] will be changed into [r, θ, z], in which r and θ are the new features that codetermine the shape of hand, you can also use z to represent the size of hand if necessary.